# Why does this UPDATE ... RETURNING return null instead of true?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to use UPDATE RETURNING to make sure the record I want to update exists.  If it doesn't, I will return it.  I don't need to get fancy, since my query will be run rarely.  I figured I'd just use something like this:

```
if UPDATE my_table SET my_field = 1 WHERE my_key = 12345 RETURNING my_field is NULL then
    perform do_something()
end if;
```

That should work, but I figured it might be cleaner if I made it a boolean expression, so I tried this in a pgAdmin SQL window:

```
update charge set pred_heat_time = 12345 where charge = 99999 returning (pred_heat_time is null)
```

I was surprised to see that this expression returns null instead of true.  Why does it do that?

Comment: since you just set the value of `my_field`, it will not be null. If the record doesn't exists at all, nothing will be returned

Comment: Use `FOUND` without `RETURNING` instead to see if you updated anything. `UPDATE x SET y ...; IF FOUND THEN ...`. Note that `UPDATE ... RETURNING field IS NULL` will not return anything if nothing was updated - there is no field value to compare against NULL, as nothing was updated, so `RETURNING` returns nothing, not NULL.